# Why is the Tipsy jQuery plugin not working for me?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, tipsy

I am using the latest version of Tipsy from here:https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy

I am including `jquery.tipsy.js` and `tipsy.css`, here is my html, the `a href` is an image:

```
<div class="social">
    <ul id="social">
        <li class="vimeo" title="Vimeo">
        <a href="#" class="vimeo" title="Vimeo"></a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.vimeo').tipsy({
        trigger: 'hover', 
        fade: true, 
        gravity: 'n'}
    );
});
```

Why is this not showing anything at all?

Comment: There is a typo in your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you are not using any text in your anchor tags

```
<div class="social">
<ul id="social">
    <li class="vimeo" title="Vimeo">
<a href="#" class="vimeo" title="Vimeo"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Put some thing here  >>

```
   <a href="#" class="vimeo" title="Vimeo">HERE</a>
```

you need to check this : http://jsfiddle.net/f4RTs/

Also your **li** and **a** tag has same class so you will see two titles on hover